# Make subplot from multiple dataframes loaded with looping through .dat files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have multiple .dat file (30) and I load them as Dataframes and add more columns:

```
A_files = glob.glob("*.A*.dat") #load .dat file which contains "A" in their name

for files in A_files:
    df=pd.read_fwf(files,header=None,infer_nrows=300,names=["Time","Result",'Error']) #loading the files as dataframes
    df['error_plus']=df["Result"]+df['Error'] #defining first curve for error bars
    df['error_minus']=df["Result"]-df['Error'] #defining second curve for error bars
```

Now I'd like to make subplots from the dataframes, where x='Time', y='Result', and 'error_plus' with 'error_minus' will serve for function ax.fill_between. I tried to extend the code above with this:

```
A_files = glob.glob("*.A*.dat")
for files in A_files:
    df=pd.read_fwf(files,header=None,infer_nrows=300,names = ["Time","Result",'Error'])
    df['error_plus']=df["Result"]+df['Error'] 
    df['error_minus']=df["Result"]-df['Error'] 

    ax=df.plot(subplots=True,x='Time', y="Result",sharey=True, sharex=True)
    ax.fill_between(df["Time"], df["error_plus"],df["error_minus"],color="r")
```

However, it didn't make subplots as I expected and this error was raised: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fill_between' (but when I plot just one dataframe without looping, then this error doesn't occurr).
Is there some easy/elegant approach how to make subplots from a loop of dataframes? And also containing fill_between function to highlight error and shared axis?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the use of `ax=df.plot()`, you need to give a previously created "matplotlib axes object" as a parameter to `df.plot()`.

You also don't need the `subplots` parameter, he has a different meaning, he says whether to plot each of df's columns in a different subplot, or all together in one subplot.
See: [pandas.DataFrame.plot documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Then you also have to tell `sharex, sharey` to the `pyplot.subplots()` function instead, because this is where you create one plot with subplots.

Here is a mockup of all the changes:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=6, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes_flat = axes.flatten()
for file, ax in zip(A_files, axes_flat):
    df = pd.read_fwf(file, ...)
    ...
    df.plot(x='Time', y="Result", ax=ax) 
plt.show()
```